# Monitoring tomcat threads and threadpool executors using Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We are doing some performance testing of our application which uses SpringBoot 2.2.2 with Spring Actuator.

We want to monitor:

1. How many tomcat threads are being used
2. How many tomcat requests are being queued
3. How many ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threads are being used (we are using @Async with a threadpool for some of the tasks)

Is this information available in the actuator? I couldn't see which metrics I needed to use.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? I think Tomcat metrics are actually there by default. But the thread pool task executor doesn't appear to be.

Answer (score 4):

By enabling Tomcats MBean Registry you will get more metrics collected, including thread pool metrics:
`server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true`

Comment: It is disabled by default since version 2.2: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#tomcats-mbean-registry